# Big O Notation proof check

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm looking to show that if you have a function $d(n)$ and it's given to be $O(f(n))$, then $d(n)$ is $O(f(n))$, for any constant $a>0$.

If it is given that $d(n)$ is $(())$, then there exists positive constants $$ and $_0$ such that for all $ \geq _0: f(n)\geq a^{-1}d(n)$, thus there must exist a positive constant $k$, namely $k=a^{-1}$ such that for all $n\geq N_0$, we have $ad(n)\geq kf(n)$ which is the definition of $ad(n)=O(f(n))$.

I'm confused on the use of the inverse. If someone could explain why this does / doesn't work, that'd help a ton!

Comment: Are you trying to show that if $d(n)=O(f(n))$ then $f(n)=O(d(n))$? Or are you trying to show that if $d(n)=O(f(n))$ then for any constant $a$, $ad(n)=O(f(n))$?

Comment: Looking to show the second.

Answer (score 0):

if $d(n) =\mathcal{O}(f(n))\iff \exists K>0, \exists n_0\ge 0,\;\forall n>n_0,\quad|d((n)|\le K|f(n)|$

so $a>0,\quad a|d((n)|\le aK|f(n)|\iff  |ad((n)|\le K'|f(n)|\iff ad(n) =\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ with $K'=aK$

Comment: @SethKillian, if it's a satisfactory answer, may you accept it please